# Use old Powerbook G4's screen

Tags: screen, powerbook

I have a broken Powerbook G4 lying around and I'm wondering if I can re-use the screen, that is still fine. Maybe it's impossible, but is there a way to use it with composite video input?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, but it's not worth it.**

The screen in that iBook is basically worthless: it's a small, not very good screen. You're better off spending any money on a slightly better display that–if nothing else–is larger.

However, if you really feel like it, you can do so.

First, you'll need to identify what display you have. Run the command `ioreg -lw0 | grep IODisplayEDID | sed "/[^<]*</s///" | xxd -p -r | strings -6`. This will output two strings. Copy the first one which should look something like "LP133WX2-TLC1", then search it. This will show you what panel it has. Using that info, search for it's controller. Using the same example [here's a VGA controller for that panel](http://www.ebay.com/itm/LVDS-VGA-Controller-Driver-board-kit-f-LCD-screen-LP133WX2-TL-G6-C1C2-LTN133AT09-/281313031688).  This will allow you to  use it as a monitor.

Again, let me reiterate: this probably isn't worth it for that panel. You can get a larger, nicer panel for the same amount of money and time you'll invest. But if you feel like doing it, go ahead.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Maybe you're right, it's not worth it, but what if I have a Raspberry Pi to use it with?

Comment: @AndreaBR Still not worth it, you'd either have to buy the controller or figure out how to drive it directly from the Raspberry Pi, which is probably going to be a lot of work.

Comment: Ok and how can I figure out the model of the panel if the computer is broken and won't boot up?

Comment: @AndreaBR You can disassemble the computer and look for identifying info. I don't know which PowerBook G4 you have, but here's an [example teardown](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/PowerBook+G4+Aluminum+15-Inch+1-1.5+GHz+Display+Replacement/229). Search iFixit for your model (they have great guides) and follow it.